# Move all files from one folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm super bad in apps script in Google drive ... I'm upset.
I need your help.

I have folders like this in my root drive :

```
students  
__kev  
___math  
___english  
__donald  
___math  
___english  
__tony  
___math  
___english  
  
transfer 
__math
```

I want to automate an operation: copy or move all the contents of the "transfer" folder to each student folder.

I can do this task easily on PowerShell or bash with a sync client but I need it directly on drive now.

Any idea ? I want to add a menu on a file with the tool script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is quite simply, but there is one trick. You need to decide what should the script do in case a destination folder already has a file with the same name. By default Google Drive allows to have many files with the same name within a folder, which can be confusing.

My script checks a target folder and removes a file with the same name (it's supposed that there is one file) before copying.

```
function main() {

  const root_folder_ID  = "###"; // here is ID of your folder
  const root_folder     = DriveApp.getFolderById(root_folder_ID);
  const transfer_folder = root_folder.getFoldersByName("transfer").next(); // transfer folder

  // get array of subjects from transfer folder
  const subjects_generator = transfer_folder.getFolders();
  var subjects = [];
  while (subjects_generator.hasNext()) {
    var subj = subjects_generator.next();
    subjects.push(subj);    
  }

  // get students folders (a generator)
  const students_folder = root_folder.getFoldersByName("students").next();
  const students = students_folder.getFolders();
  
  // copy all subject folders (with content) into students folders
  while(students.hasNext()) {
    var student = students.next();
    for (var s in subjects) {
      Logger.log("folder '" + subjects[s] + "' started to copy to '" + student + "'");
      copy_folder(subjects[s], student);
      Logger.log("---");
    }
  }

}


function copy_folder(source_folder, target_folder) {

  // pick or create subject subfolder within target folder
  try {
    var subfolder = target_folder.getFoldersByName(source_folder.getName()).next();
  } catch(e) {
    var subfolder = target_folder.createFolder(source_folder.getName());
  }

  // get all files from source folder
  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  // copy the files into the subfolder
  while(files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var file_name = file.getName();

    // try to remove old file with the same name in the target folder
    try {
      var old_file = subfolder.getFilesByName(file_name).next();
      old_file.setTrashed(true);
      Logger.log("old file '" + old_file + "' was removed")
    } catch(e) {}

    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), subfolder);
    Logger.log("file '" + file + "' is copied")
  }

}
```

To run this script you have to create a new document somewhere on Google Drive, go the menu 'Tools' and click on 'Script Editor'.

[image]

Then you need to paste the text of the script into the editor and click the 'Run' icon:

[image]

But first you need to paste your folder ID into the second line of the script of course.

Alternatively you can make a custom menu in your document and run the script from there, without Script editor.

To make a custom menu just add this function at the end (or start) of the script in Script editor:

```
// custom menu
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Scripts')
  .addItem(' Copy files', 'main')
  .addToUi();
}
```

And you'll get the custom menu 'Script' after reload your document:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your needs. Adapted from: [this site](https://www.labnol.org/code/19979-copy-folders-drive). Change the id's of the two folders.

```
function start() {

  var transfertFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx-YhSCZXh1PDeqpE8mXjHHJJF");
  var studentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx_cQgd3DZV9Ukt4yI_-jTS_86Z").getFolders();

  while (studentFolder.hasNext()){
    const student = studentFolder.next()
    copyFolder(transfertFolder,student)
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files = source.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }

}
```